# a problem about wxpython listctrl

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I got a GUI application implemented in wxpython, on the main window, there is a listctrl used to dispaly the names of the files. it was empty at the very beginning. the user clicks the "File", then "open", then chooses a file to open, when this is done by clicking on the "ok" button, the names of the file is supposed to be display in the listctrl. But it seems that this does not work. I used a `print` clause to check, the `print` clause works. Here are my codes:

```
def OnDisplay(self):
    print "On display called"
    self.lc1.InsertStringItem(0, "level 1")
    self.lc1.InsertStringItem(1, "level 2")
    self.lc1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

    print self.lc1.GetItemText(0)
    print self.lc1.GetItemText(1)

    self.lc1.Refresh()
```

`lc1` is the listctrl, it was initialized at the very beginning when the main window was lauched, but when the `OnDisplay` was triggered, the `print "On display called"` works, and the following two `print` clauses also work. but the listctrl on the main window did not change, i mean, did not show the `level 1` and `level 2`, nor did the background of the listctrl was changed to red, what is the reason please? many thanks!

Comment: Works fine on python 2.6, wxpython 2.8, windows 7.

Comment: @volting: well, I use python2.6 and the windows vista...

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between vista and 7. Maybe something else in your code is affecting... Ill post a runnable example and you can see if that works for you

Comment: @volting: thanks, I will check the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a runnable example that works on Windows 7, Python 2.6, wx 2.8.

```
import wx

class ListTest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(380, 230))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT) 
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'col 1', width=140)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.onKey)

    def onKey(self, evt):
        if evt.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_DOWN:
            self.list.InsertStringItem(0, "level 1")
            self.list.InsertStringItem(1, "level 2")
            self.list.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
            self.list.Refresh()

            print self.list.GetItemText(0)
            print self.list.GetItemText(1)
        else:
            evt.Skip()


app = wx.App()
ListTest(None, 'list test')
app.MainLoop()
```